# Repeating error of undefined control sequence even after removing the sequence

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I copied a bibtex citation from here: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018PhRvD..98c0001T/exportcitation
As you can see that defines `journal={\prd}`. I added the citation to my essay and run the build. It resulted in `!Undefined control sequence. \newblock {\em \prd` error. I've realized it is caused by this journal sequence so I changed it to `journal={Physics Review D}"`. But the error does not want to disappear. I tried removing the citation, closing the bib file and tex file, but nothing. I do not have the `\prd` sequence anywhere else and before adding this item the document compiled just fine. I have encountered that problem before but it resolved by itself, now it seems to be stuck. I use TexMaker on Ubuntu. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Remove the `.bbl` file and try again

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: Partially. In my case `.bbl` indeed did not updated for some reason but not the reason in the linked answer (I have the correct compilation chain automatically configured in TexMaker and it works most of the time, fails only with certain macros in bib files).

Comment: That's because when the `.bbl` file is generated, BibTeX doesn't know it contains an unknown macro (control sequence), so as far as it knows, everything is fine.  Only later, LaTeX complains about that.  The solution is then to fix the `.bib` file, and remove the `.bbl` so that it can be generated again